# How to get a date displayed in Hebrew calendar with MSFT AJAX library client(Sys namespace)?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I want to display a date with the culture "he-IL" and the Hebrew calendar, but I have not had any success. I'm getting the following:

Expected:
יום שלישי ט"ז אייר תשע"ב

Actual:
יום שלישי 08 שבט 2012

Just one part of the date is being dispalyed correctly, any ideas why is this happening? Here is one example using C# (It displays the date correctly) and another with Javascript (it does not display the date correctly):

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" >
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo() {
        var d = new Date();
        var p = document.getElementById("txtHebrewDateJS");
        p.value = d.localeFormat(Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.dateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
    }
</script>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Hebrew calendar, culture he-IL, using code behind" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHebrewDate" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hebrew calendar, culture he-IL, using asp net ajax" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtHebrewDateJS"  />
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="load hebrew date" onclientclick="foo();" />
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        txtHebrewDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
    }

    protected override void InitializeCulture() { 
        var c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("he-IL"); 
        c.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new HebrewCalendar(); 
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = c; 
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = c; 
        base.InitializeCulture(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string HebrewDate(string dateString)
  {
   DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);             

   var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL");
   ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new HebrewCalendar();
   return date.ToString("D", ci);
  }
```

If you don't want to display the day of week, You can change line:

```
return date.ToString("D", ci);
```

into:

```
return date.ToString("d", ci);
```

Source: [Shimmy's comment on C# and iOS Programming blog](http://csharpprogramming.blogspot.co.il/2005/03/c-hebrew-date.html)